# How to convert the following text format into 5x4 table using ' ' as delimiter??(' ' there lies no space in between 'but single quotes)

Tags: python, csv

```
'Aabhas' 'The sense Feelings (1)' '5' 'Boy' '' 'Aabhat' 'Shining Visible' '6' 'Boy' '' 'Aabheer' 'A cowherd Name of dynasty' '4' 'Boy' '' 'Aabir' 'Gulal' '22' 'Boy' '' 'Aacharya' 'Teacher' '4' 'Boy'
```

This can be considered as text file.But finally outcome should be like having 4 columns with titles 'Name','Meaning','Nemerology','Gender'.

```
import csv
import itertools
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as in_file:
     stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
     lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
     group = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 4)
with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as out_file:
     writer = csv.writer(out_file)
     writer.writerow(('Name', 'Meaning', 'Numerology','Gender'))
     writer.writerows(group)
```

This just creates a table with the titles but not adding the data from text file.. Instead could someone help to get it using '' as seperator to add data.

Comment: show some of your original data

Comment: posted above .. check once

Comment: use `text.split(separator)`

Comment: Its not only using that as seperator but have to make the above text into a tabular format

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Tabular format for the text given..

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this is already a list. If it's one big string with single quotes being use as a separator use `str.split("''")` first

```
words = ['Aabhas', 'The sense Feelings (1)', '5', 'Boy', '',\
 'Aabhat', 'Shining Visible', '6', 'Boy', '',\
 'Aabheer', 'A cowherd Name of dynasty', '4', 'Boy', '',\
'Aabir', 'Gulal', '22', 'Boy', '',\
 'Aacharya', 'Teacher', '4', 'Boy']
```

I'm going to assuming you want it looking something like this. Will need to tinker with it to get a nicer looking table which I'll leave up to you. But this should be the brunt of it.

```
for item in words:
    if item:
        print '{0:<25}'.format(item), end=' '
    else:
        print

#Output
Aabhas                    The sense Feelings (1)    5                         Boy                       
Aabhat                    Shining Visible           6                         Boy                       
Aabheer                   A cowherd Name of dynasty 4                         Boy                       
Aabir                     Gulal                     22                        Boy                       
Aacharya                  Teacher                   4                         Boy
```

Comment: print('{0:<25}'.format(item), end = ' ')  it creates a syntax error.. But in case of large text file we dont know the size of table too.. we know only number of columns every 5th value should come in the second row

Comment: The questions asks 5x4. This code will print everything in the list into 4 columns assuming your `''` are after every 4 items in the list. Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Its a large text file.. given some sample text here.. Using python 2.3. Still getting error with end =' ' in print line

Comment: After searching the python 2 equivalent I get `print '{0:<25}'.format(var), end=' '` which I'll add to answer